# Trigger BEFORE INSERT from date to datetime

Tags: mysql, trigger, datetime, date

I have this schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `id_product` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL, # Important: DATE
  `value` decimal(8,5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`, `date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `prices_changes` (
  `id_product` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL, # Important: DATETIME
  `value` decimal(8,5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000'
  KEY (`id_product`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `prices_before_insert`
  BEFORE INSERT ON `prices`
  FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO `prices_changes` (`id_product`, `date`, `value`) VALUES (NEW.`id_product`, NEW.`date`, NEW.`value`);;
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO `prices` SET
  `id_product` = 1,
  `date` = "2016-08-11 13:50:00", # Is a DATETIME value
  `value` = "20.50"
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = VALUES(`value`);

mysql> SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE id_product = 1;
+------------+------------+---------+
| id_product | date       | value   |
+------------+------------+---------+
| 1          | 2016-08-11 | 20.50   |
+------------+------------+---------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM `prices_changes` WHERE id_product = 1;
+------------+---------------------+---------+
| id_product | date                | value   |
+------------+---------------------+---------+
| 1          | 2016-08-11 00:00:00 | 20.50   |
+------------+---------------------+---------+
```

It should update `prices` table with last value without product/date duplicates and insert into `prices_changes` all updates using a trigger.

The problem is that in `prices_changes` the `date` column defined as `datetime` is storing the date value without the time.

How can I store into the `prices_changes` the data as `datetime` using the original value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems each time you are inserting data into both tables i.e. `price_changes` and `prices`. Reverse process may be helpful. 
If possible  try this :

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `prices_changes_before_insert`
   BEFORE INSERT ON `prices_changes`
   FOR EACH ROW
   INSERT INTO `prices` (`id_product`, `date`, `value`) VALUES (NEW.`id_product`, NEW.`date`, NEW.`value`)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = VALUES(`value`);;
DELIMITER ;
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO `prices_changes` SET
   `id_product` = 3,
    `date` = "2016-08-12 14:50:00", # Is a DATETIME value
    `value` = "20.50";
```

Comment: Yes, it's a possible solution, but prices must be inserted in `prices` table and not in `prices_changes`.

Comment: in your query manual entry will be done in `prices` table which triggered an entry in`prices_changes` .... in my case manual entry will be done in `prices_changes` table which triggered an entry to `prices` table..in both case two entry will be done but order will be changed.

Comment: Yes, I know, but for some requirements the first INSERT must be `prices`. Anyway it's a possible solution. I don't undertand why the NEW.date has not the original hour. Maybe the NEW trigger values are coverted as original INSERT?

Comment: as per docs `NEW.col_name refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.` That's why it is truncating the time part first then insert to `prices_changes`